# My second Riley riddle likes exercise

Tags: riddle, word

Here is my second Riley riddle. hope you like it!

> My prefix is very evil and full of death,
>
> My infix is a tree that originated in what is now central Asia,
>
> My suffix I have just become acquainted with,
>
> And altogether I protect you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a

> helmet

My prefix is very evil and full of death

> hell

My infix is a tree that originated in what is now central Asia,

> elm

My suffix I have just become acquainted with,

> met

And altogether I protect you.

> helmet

Comment: Was that too easy?

Comment: @Yout Ried if yes, please try doing mine! Thanks!